# Analysis of Op-Amp with Positive and Negative Feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, positive-feedback

I'm trying to understand the analysis of the following schematic:

[image]

Specifically, the following line of logic

[image]

Where the authors claim that the transfer function of the LC tank H(jw) is written with the R3 resistor. The closest I've gotten to reverse engineering the expression is assuming that R3 is somehow placed in parallel with C and L, but even then you are left with an extra R3 multiplying the numerator term.

---

The diagram was wrong in the original report. The proper diagram should look like this I think:

[image]

If done like this, then you can cut the wire at the output and do the correct loop gain analysis.

Comment: The schematic on the left doesn't match the system representation on the right in the slightest.

Comment: Ok, this is annoying. The original resource that had this diagram was from here https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/s2016/projects/djgomez_Project_Final_Report_s.pdf. I also realized that in their report they connected their NIC wrong. If connected correctly, the math works out, but the signs end up swapped.

Comment: Something is missing at the node with R3 & (+) input of op-amp.  The circuit can not function as drawn.

Comment: You claim that hte 1st diagram was wrong! Where is the error? Both circuits have 100% positive feedback. No input node? No linear operation possible.